# Merge JSON array values using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two JSON arrays with some values. I need to merge those values in a format using PHP. Here is the array format and the output format that I needed:

Array 1:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "red"
        },
    "25": {
        "id": 3, 
            "name": "green"
        }
        }
}
```

Array 2:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "10": {
            "id": 14, 
            "name": "blue"
        },
    "22": {
        "id": 5, 
            "name": "white"
        }
        }
}
```

Expected Result after merge:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "red"
        },
    "25": {
        "id": 3, 
            "name": "green"
        }
        },
        "10": {
            "id": 14, 
            "name": "blue"
        },
    "22": {
        "id": 5, 
            "name": "white"
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: okay.. and where is your code that is trying to achieve this?

Comment: Decode them into arrays, and then run `array_merge()` on them…?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $json1 = '{
            "data": {
                "1": {
                    "id": 1, 
                    "name": "red"
                },
                "25": {
                    "id": 3, 
                        "name": "green"
                    }
                }
            }';

    $json2 = '{
            "data": {
                "10": {
                    "id": 14, 
                    "name": "blue"
                },
                "22": {
                    "id": 5, 
                    "name": "white"
                }
            }
        }';

    // Decode json into array
    $jArray1 = json_decode($json1, true);
    $jArray2 = json_decode($json2, true);

    // Merging array
    $merge['data']  = $jArray1['data'] + $jArray2['data'];

    // Encoding array to json
    $mergedJson = json_encode($merge);

    print_r( $mergedJson );
?>
```

Comment: Oops, this is not exactly like the format that I expect. When you take a look at the expected output, there is index missing. For example after "data" index, "1" is missing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay, I have changed code according to your format. Please check once.

Comment: Yes, that works. I didn't expect that was so simple. Many thanks, Sateesh.

Answer (score 0):

```
$de_json = json_decode('{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "red"
    },
"25": {
    "id": 3, 
        "name": "green"
    }
    }}', True);

echo '<pre>';print_r($de_json);
```

You will get this output

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => red
                )

            [25] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => green
                )

        )

)
```

the convert other two json array to php array and 
use `array_merge()` to get the merged array.